# Unlock using pin but elevate with full password

Tags: windows, security, passwords, uac, windows-11

I would like to be able to set up my Mom's computer so that she can unlock and login using her pin but then require her full password when elevating, e.g. installing a new program, changing her security settings, or revealing her other passwords. The reason is that she is using the same pin as she uses for the house alarm and everyone in the house knows it, including her grandkids and she doesn't mind them using her computer so is likely to just give out the pin if she changes it. But she has a more secure password that she doesn't give out for her Microsoft account. I know I'm looking for a technical solution for a social problem but there it is.

She is using Windows 11 Home Edition. Is this even possible?

Comment: Create a separate Administrator account, do not assigned this account a pin, verify existing account is NOT an Administrator account.

Comment: Sorry, I do not want to lock her out of her own computer. I may not always be around. Also if I do that she might still save her other passwords on the computer.

Comment: There is no other way to achieve what you want in that case.